# What is Monero current communication protocol?

Tags: p2p

There is a lot of info about on-blockchain privacy, much less about actual peer to peer communications (or I'm extremely bad at finding it). What are the message types (the analogy to inv/addr/getdata/tx/block of Bitcoin)? How are the messages that will end up being TCP packets created? Are they encrypted? Can someone intercepting the packet on a routing path determine whether it's Monero related?

Comment: p2p vulnerabilities (as opposed to blockchain analysis) seems to have received too little attention in general. There is some discussion of a solution for bitcoin and I too wonder if there is something analogous for Monero: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04439.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Monero uses UDP for sharing the blockchain, although I'm unsure what it uses for actually broadcasting transactions.

To answer the content of your question though regarding privacy when doing p2p communication, in April 2020 (2 years after your post), Monero [merged](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6314) Dandelion++, a feature that changes how messages are propagated through the p2p network.

Dandelion++ is likely what you're looking for regarding a private p2p communication protocol, so feel free to read more it here: https://www.monerooutreach.org/stories/dandelion.html

Comment: This is incorrect. It uses TCP for all communications. The ideal configuration for a node has blocks being relayed on the clearweb, while relayed transactions are sent through TOR/I2P, however this is not the default out-of-the-box configuration.